# Running mysql -vvv from a script and I get no logging

Tags: mysql, file, logging

I am having a problem getting mysql -vvv to output to a log file from a script.  Redhat Linux, mysql 5

I can run the following from the Linux command line and I get SQL command output to the screen just like I would expect.  Work fine and tells me what I want to know.

> mysql -vvv --user=username --pass=password < /path/script.sql

When I add the following to a Linux bash shell script, I do not get and output to the log file.  What do I not understand?

> mysql -vvv --user=username --pass=password < /path/script.sql  >>  /tmp/file.log

NOTE:  Database connect string is inside my script.sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL verbose uses the error output, try this:

```
mysql -vvv --user=username --pass=password < /path/script.sql 2>&1 >> /tmp/file.log
```

`2>&1` redirect the error to standard output